# What if SpringBoot WebFlux project will use blocking JDBC driver?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-jdbc

I'm starting SpringBoot WebFlux project, but what if I use usual ( non-reactive) jdbc driver? Will the whole application stop to be reactive?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You will either lead to blocking due to threadpool exhaustion, or if its unbounded, resource exhaustion.

In addition, there is no such thing as backpressure in non reactive drivers a key tenet of reactive programming.

Answer (score 2):

No.

[C.1. How Do I Wrap a Synchronous, Blocking Call?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking)

It is often the case that a source of information is synchronous and blocking. To deal with such sources in your Reactor applications, apply the following pattern:

```
Mono blockingWrapper = Mono.fromCallable(() -> { 
    return /* make a remote synchronous call */ 
});
blockingWrapper = blockingWrapper.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

- Create a new Mono by using fromCallable.
- Return the asynchronous, blocking resource.
- Ensure each subscription happens on a dedicated single-threaded worker from Schedulers.boundedElastic().

You should use a Mono, because the source returns one value. You should use Schedulers.boundedElastic, because it creates a dedicated thread to wait for the blocking resource without impacting other non-blocking processing, while also ensuring that there is a limit to the amount of threads that can be created, and blocking tasks that can be enqueued and deferred during a spike.

Note that subscribeOn does not subscribe to the Mono. It specifies what kind of Scheduler to use when a subscribe call happens.